# Sens de la phrase « tête d'ange gris »

Tags: sens, adjectifs

Ce peut être une question simple, mais j'ai compris que je ne sais pas de réponse. Dans la phrase « tête d'ange gris », est-ce que la tête est grise ou l'ange est gris ? Cette phrase est de un livre sur Salvador Dalí, et je suis sûr que la traduction en anglais est « gray head of angel », pas « head of gray angel », mais je ne sais pas pourquoi.

Comment: Le titre original de l’œuvre de Savador Dali est *Tête d'un ange gris* (1952). Elle est traduite en anglais par *Head of a Gray Angel*, ce qui est la bonne traduction, je n'en vois pas de meilleure. La traduction anglaise que tu signales dans ta question est de toute façon mauvaise (*gray head of an angel* serait en anglais correct, mais infidel au titre donné par Dali pour qui c'est l'ange qui était gris)

Comment: @Laure, dans ce cas, nous avons trouvé une erreur dans le livre ! Je posséde ce livre papier (en français). « Dalí » de Gilles Néret, page 73 « à droite : Tête d'ange gris (Grey Head of Angel) ». Je ne sais pas pourquoi il y a traduction en anglais dans le livre en français...

Comment: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_%C5%93uvres_de_Salvador_Dal%C3%AD  et http://www.dali-gallery.com/html/allworks_c.htm

Comment: @Laure, Oui, « gray head of angel » est une mauvaise traduction.

Comment: Gilles Neret est un spécialiste de l'art mais peut-être pas de Dali? Je n'ai pas le titre espagnol mais tu trouveras des références en anglais et en français sur internet. De toute façon ta question de français est tout à fait légitime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'accord de l'adjectif se fait par rapport au nom qu'il qualifie :

> Tête d'ange *gris*

gris au masculin, c'est *l'ange* qui est gris.

> Tête d'ange *grise*

gris au féminin, c'est *la tête* qui est grise.

Answer (score 1):

« gray head of angel » se traduit par « tête d'ange grise ».

C'est la tête de l'ange qui est grise et non pas l'ange qui est gris.

Comment: Eh bien, mais c'est juste un exemple. En général, dans une construction « X de Y gris », quand X et Y sont les deux de genre masculin, X est gris ou Y est gris ?

Comment: Cela dépend entièrement du contexte. Cette simple phrase ne suffit pas pour décider.